# How to stop wrapping comments in P tag

Tags: filters

When I update a comment in wordpress, the comment is wrapped with p tag.

Here's my code

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'pre_comment_content', 'wp_filter_kses');
return wp_update_comment( $data );
```

I removed the `wpautop` filter but the problem didn't disappear. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments aren't part of the post body. Those won't be effected by the filters that you are trying to use. The [core front end comment filters are these](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/default-filters.php#L146):

```
146 add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wptexturize'            );
147 add_filter( 'comment_text', 'convert_chars'          );
148 add_filter( 'comment_text', 'make_clickable',      9 );
149 add_filter( 'comment_text', 'force_balance_tags', 25 );
150 add_filter( 'comment_text', 'convert_smilies',    20 );
151 add_filter( 'comment_text', 'wpautop',            30 );
```

You will want to do something like:

```
remove_filter('comment_text','wpautop',30);
```

With `remove_filter()` the priority hook isn't when `remove_filter()` runs, it is the priority of the callback that you are removing. It has to match.